# How do i make my margins to fit on many resolutions?

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout, margins

This is the first web site i'm making in my life, so your help is much appriciated! I'm still learning html and css. My first site is almost finished, except I have built it for my native resolution - 1280x800. When i change resolution, elements go apart. For that to compensate, i only need to change the value of the right margin in a body property. For example, it is currently 7em. If i want to look centered in resolution 1920x1200, value should be 27em. I've tried with site-wrapper and @media query techniques but that seems not to work. Solution is obviously simple, but i can't figure it out on my own.

Please help me!

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
        <title>Autoprevoznik Damjanić</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="Autoprevoznik Damjanić / Prevoz robe / Špediterske usluge" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Damjanić, autoprevoznik, špediter, prevoz robe, špediterske usluge" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="naslovna.css" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Truck.ico" />
</head>

<body>

<h1><a href="naslovna.html">:::Autoprevoznik Damjanić</a></h1>

<div id="border_left"></div>
<ul>
    <li><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt Informacije</a></li>
    <li><a href="galerija.html">Galerija slika</a></li>
    <li id="empty"><a href="onama.html">O nama</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="border_right"></div>

<div id="content">
    <p>Ispum schmipsum.</p>
</div>

<div class="background">
<div class="border">
<div id="box1">
    <h2>Ukratko o nama</h2>
    <h3>Usluge prevoza</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
<div class="button" ><a href="galerija.html"  style="text-decoration:none" title="Galerija slika" class="read_more">galerija</a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="background">
<div class="border">
<div id="box2">
    <h2>Aktuelnosti</h2>
    <h3>Poslednje vesti</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
<div class="button" ><a href="onama.html"  style="text-decoration:none" title="Detaljnije" class="read_more">detaljnije</a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="background">
<div class="border">
<div id="box3">
    <h2>Kontakt informacije</h2>
    <h3>Identifikacija preduzeća</h3>
<p>Možete nas kontaktirati na brojeve telefona :</p>

<p>+381 (0) 6</p>

<p>+381 (0) 34</p>

<p>Email:</p>
 <div class="button" ><a href="kontakt.html" style="text-decoration:none" title="Detaljnije" class="read_more">detaljnije</a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And my CSS:

```
body  {
    background:url(background.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;   
    background-position: top center;
    background-color:#b0d3f6;
    margin: 3em 7em 0em;
    }

p {
    font-size: 11px;
    margin: 0px 30px 0px 0px;
    color: rgb(111, 130, 150);
    line-height: 18px;
    text-align: left;
}

h1 a {
    color: rgb(27, 63, 150);
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: rgb(27, 63, 98);
    margin-bottom: -5px;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: rgb(84, 130, 175);
}

#box1, #box2, #box3 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 306px;
    background: url(box_top.png) top left no-repeat;
    padding: 0px 18px;
    position: relative;
    top: -35px;
}

.border {
    display: inline-block;
    background: url(box_bottom.png) bottom left no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    top: 17px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.background {
    display: inline-block;
    background: url(box_in.png) repeat-y;
}

.button {
    position: relative;
    left: -10px;
    width: 77px;
    height: 19px;
    line-height: 16px;
    background: url("button.png") no-repeat;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px 10px 0px;
}

a { color:white;}

ul {
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    top: -35px;
    left: -60px;
    list-style: none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height: 48px;
    line-height: 70px;
    background: url("menu_back.png") no-repeat;
}

ul a {
    color:  rgb(113, 136, 157);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 45px;
    display:block;
}

ul li {
    background: url("menu_line.png") no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin: 7px 0px 0px;
    height: 40px;
}

li { 
    float: right;
    border-bottom-width: 0;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

#content {
    position: relative;
    top: -35px;
    clear: both;
    width: 1005px;
    height: 247px;
    background: url("slider_back.png") no-repeat;
}

#content p {
    margin-left: 2em;
}

#border_left {
    background: url("menu_back_left.png") no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    right: 440px;
    top: -35px;
    height: 48px;
    width: 11px;
    float: right;
}

#border_right {
    background: url("menu_back_right.png")no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    right: -320px;
    top: -35px;
    height: 48px;
    width: 11px;
    float: right;
}

#empty {
    background: none;
}
```

As you see, only problematic line is margin: 3em 7em 0em; If i could make right margin value (7em) fluid, problem will be solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to **center** your webpage? If you want to center it I recommend use:

```
margin: 0 auto; /*left and right margin are "automatic"*/
```

You can use this to center your body in any resolution:

```
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
}
```

If you put 100% the content has full width so there is nothing  to center. If you want center another thing, the box you want to center should have less width than his parent.

Anyway using values in the body element to center **is't good**.

Comment: I've tried that, but it didn't help. I want my page to stay in the center of the screen in all resolutions. In 1280x800 it's ok, but if I switch to 1900x1200 the upper navigation element (div#border left and div#border right with <ul>) goes to the far right, with everything else too far to the left. If I change right margin value on the body property from 7em to 27em everything is suddenly in the right place. If I set to a values you provided, it's still not good. Upper navigation element is much to the left, and rightest box element of the main content falls down in a new line.

Comment: So sorry but your document is a caos... I can't imagine what do you want to do. Moreover you are making relative A LOT of elements which is bad. If you want center something on top (a header) you can use the same I write in the solution. #ħeader{width: 400px; margin: 0 auto}.

Comment: All your problems are with **all the relative elements in your web page**. A suggestion that you must conscientiously follow: *If you set display: relative; to a box is because you are doing something wrong*. When you have in the future more knowledge you will know when to use this position while I suggest you use the natural flux in all document (floats are allowed).

Comment: This is how I made it, in original 1280x800: http://i50.tinypic.com/dcsg9g.png This is how It looks like when I switch to 1920x1200: http://i48.tinypic.com/27wu5vn.png This is how It looks like when I change right margin on body to 27em, and obviously this is how i would like to be on all resolutions: http://i46.tinypic.com/16kuetl.png And this is how It looks like with margin: 0 auto; on wrapper or on body, no matter: http://i46.tinypic.com/1547jif.png

Comment: Wait a moment while I am making the basic html and css structure for you. But remember the suggestion I said before.

Comment: Here is the structure: http://jsfiddle.net/ZLKw6/ if you don't want % just use fixed values. For example, #superContainer {width: 800px;}

Comment: Thank you very much, José! I will need some tome to recheck my code and to try your code structure. As you see, i am using much of relative position because of rounded corners of my elements. Anyway thanks.

Comment: I have tried your structure, but it didn't helped me out :( In order to look centered in 1900x1200, I must set the width of #superContainer to 50%. Needless to say, with the same width in 1200x800 everything fall out of place. I'm beginning to think that this can't be done without some js code.

Comment: Could you paste what you did to a jsfiddle? 50% of width means that the superContainer will have exactly the half of the width of the body. Just all.

Comment: My basic mistake is that for the first site in my life, I'm actually trying to recreate web page created in WordPress, from scratch with my code. Guess that wasn't so smart. The original site probably have some script that change width of site depending on resolution. On 1900x1200 is 50%, on lower resolution, it is more like 80%. Guess that's impossible only with basic css&html and that's what i was trying to do. In addition, original design have many broad corners which I was trying to achieve with relative positioning of elements.

Comment: Maybe I should start building sites in WordPress and parallely learn html&css?

Comment: Are you sure that the site is changing its size dynamically? instead of using % **you can use px for width**. For example. If you want a site of 800px: **width: 800px;** That's all. Wordpress themes (and all CMS in fact) require certain level of CSS+HTML so you will get the same problems or maybe worst. The structure I put for you is the super-basic structure for any website. I recommend you find or ask certain solutions and learn about it when you are researching.

Comment: Here's the model site that I've been trying to copy, have a look yourself, and try it with different resolutions: http://www.europalete.com/ Everything stays in place. Thank you for your time, you've been a great help to this n00b ;) I will continue to practice, until I find a solution.

Comment: This site isn't the best in the html structure. Anyway it uses what I said you before. The #con1 element has fixed width. If you remove the non standard property align="center" from #con0 and add to #con1 you will get top part of the site centered.

Comment: Solution was simpler than anything! At first, I reverted back to my original code (with lots of relative positioned elements ;) and then just added one line of code to body property - width: 1060px and changed right margin in the body property from 7em to auto; Thank you again José for giving me insights!